# Windows 7 - Everyone Permission Changed to No Control

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I accidentally set the permission of Everyone of a folder to no control, now I cannot change to permission setting because I have no control, I cannot delete the folder.

Is this process reversible?

If you want further information on why I did this and how I cannot change back, read the following:

So I have this great software called Xunlei or Thunder for super fast downloading and torrenting, but it sometimes fires a ad popup on startup. So I want to change the permission of the popup .exe folder so it won't get opened. Being confused for a moment, I changed the "Everyone" permission (Saw this the first time) to Deny All Control, and you know being a Win 7 user, you OK wherever there's a User Control Alert. Then, I wanted to changed back because The software fires a alert constantly, saying "Cannot Access File"... That's the story.

Comment: what do you mean "no control"? And Everyone is the only user on that folder? Try to take ownership of the folder- Goto Folder Options in the control panel, select the "View" tab and uncheck "Use Sharing Wizard". Now go back to the folder and right click and goto Security | Advance | etc...

Comment: What do you mean `Xunlei or Thunder for super fast downloading and torrenting`? FWIK Xunlei is a leecher software, SHAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `cmd` as Administrator, run command:

Reset NTFS permission disk C:

```
cd \
icacls * /T /Q /C /RESET
```

Reset NTFS permission and registry permission to default Windows 7:

```
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose
```

Reset NTFS permission at folder to default:

```
ICACLS "C:\Folfer Name" /RESET /T /C
```

Comment: This is a bit overkill for just changing the permission on *one* folder, isn't it?

Comment: So, this will change all my permission, right? But I change a lot of folder permission for various reasons, is there a way except doing this?

Comment: @DanielCheung `ICACLS "C:\FolderName" /reset /T /C`